# problem with dependent comboboxes fill

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I have a windows form and user select cloth parameters from comboboxes like country-state-city
method. and my parameters are :

```
typeName - typeNo - pattern - variant
R - 125 - 254978 - 1
R - 125 - 254979 - 1
R - 125 - 254979 - 2
Ri- 54 - 54658 - 1
Ri- 54 - 54658 - 2... etc.
```

I fill the typeNameCombobox on formLoad 
after than typeNoCombobox fill in the typeNameCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged() event
and like this patternCombobox fill in the typeNoCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged() event ...

but there is a problem in typeNameCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged()
the error message says that:

The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.

and a use this absurd method

```
if (typeNameCombobox .SelectedValue.ToString() != "System.Data.DataRowView")
{
 fill -> typeNoCombobox
}
```

altought this four comboboxes are dependent, the comboboxes below arent filling on firs load .

and I use second absurd method

```
typeName.selectedIndex = 1;
typeName.selectedIndex = 0;
typeName.selectedIndex = 1;
typeName.selectedIndex = 0;
```

(I have to make this minimum 4 times because there are four dependent comboboxes )

after the all of the comboboxes fill there is no problem if user changes typeName  all of the dependent values are changin

are there any way to make this code clearly?

edit after response:

tipTur=typename 
tip = typeNo
desen = pattern
varyant = variant

here are my  original code

```
 ConnectionClassOleDb cc = new ConnectionClassOleDb();


    private void SiparisDetay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //formload
        {            

            sorgu = "Select distinct tipTurId, tipTur from View_Tip order by tipTur";
            cc.cbDoldur(sorgu, cbTipTur, "tipTur", "tipTurId"); 

            cbTipTur.SelectedIndex = 1;
            cbTipTur.SelectedIndex = 0;
            cbTipTur.SelectedIndex = 1;
            cbTipTur.SelectedIndex = 0;       

        }



    private void cbTipTur_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            if (cbTipTur.SelectedValue.ToString() != "System.Data.DataRowView")
            {
                string sorgu = "SELECT distinct tipNo FROM tblTip where " +
                    " tipTurId = '" + cbTipTur.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ORDER BY tipNo";
                cc.cbDoldur(sorgu, cbTip, "tipNo", "tipNo");

            }
        }

        private void cbTip_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbTip.SelectedValue.ToString() != "System.Data.DataRowView")
            {
                string sorgu = "SELECT desen FROM tblTip WHERE " +
                    " tipTurId = '" + cbTipTur.SelectedValue.ToString() +
                    "' AND tipNo = '" + cbTip.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' order by desen";
                cc.cbDoldur(sorgu, cbDesen, "desen", "desen");
            }
        }

        private void cbDesen_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbDesen.SelectedValue.ToString() != "System.Data.DataRowView")
            {
                string sorgu = "SELECT varyant FROM tblTip WHERE " +
                               " desen = '" + cbDesen.SelectedValue.ToString() +
                               "' AND tipTurId = '" + cbTipTur.SelectedValue.ToString() +
                               "' AND tipNo = '" + cbTip.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' ORDER BY varyant";
                cc.cbDoldur(sorgu, cbVaryant, "varyant", "varyant");
            }
        }
```

and codes in connectionclass like this:

```
public void cbDoldur(string sorgu, ComboBox cb, string text, string value) //fill combobox
        {        
            DataTable dtDdl = Dt(sorgu);
            cb.DataSource = dtDdl;
            cb.DisplayMember = text;
            cb.ValueMember = value;            

            if (cb.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

        }


 public DataTable Dt(string query)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (Open())
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
                try
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sistem Mesajı:" + ex.Message, "Hata", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            //connection.Close();
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code,i think you are binding incorrectly for the dependent queries

Comment: Ok I add the original code which I use

Comment: How about changing `distinct tipNo as tipNo`, add the alias and also `distinct tipTurId as tipTurId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem to changing my comboboxpopulate function in class like this

```
cb.DisplayMember = text;
cb.ValueMember = value;
cb.DataSource = dtDdl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding Alias to the fieldnames in the query for

```
Select distinct tipTurId, tipTur from View_Tip
```

To

```
Select distinct tipTurId as tipTurId , tipTur from View_Tip
```

And also in this case `SELECT distinct tipNo FROM tblTip` to

```
SELECT distinct tipNo as tipNo FROM tblTip
```

because it would fail to find fields in the DataSource as `tipTurId` since it would returned with Distinct , same is the case with `tipNo`

Comment: no not workedand I looked at the data set visualizer and there are fields names you can look
[link](http://i.imgur.com/Y1D8v.jpg)